# How to load source for video in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I changed the src of the source

```
    <video controls height="500" width="750">
<source src="/path"/>
</video>
```

How can I load the player with the new src in react.js?

Answer (score -1):

You should use state or props, they will  call Render method if find changes. Than simply move your src to Video element. Your code should looks like this:

```
<video src={this.state.src} controls height="500" width="750"/>
```

Comment: I do use state to change the src but it does not change to the new video.

Comment: Than, please provide more detailed question, i can't figure it out from existing context. Any way i edited my answer, hope it fix your problem.

Comment: I fixed it. Using the link.